# Rspec and prevent tests from being run under some circumstances

Tags: ruby, rspec

I use rspec like this:

describe
   it 'should check if the xx':
   end

How do I prevent some tests in the it end body from being run if some condition is met? For example, if the function is_disabled returns true then the following tests should not run:

```
   it 'should check if the xx1':
   end

   it 'should check if the xx2':
   end
```

but the following should:

```
   it 'should check if the xx3':
   end

   it 'should check if the xx4':
   end
```

can you do :

```
context "if api calls enabled for MC, @app.is_disabled => 'USD' do
   it 'should check if the xx3':
   end

   it 'should check if the xx4':
   end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **[rspec implicit filters](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-3/docs/filtering/implicit-filters)**. Example:

```
describe "if the app is enabled", :unless => @app.is_disabled do
   it 'should check if the xx3':
   end

   it 'should check if the xx4':
   end
end

describe "if the app is disabled", :if => @app.is_disabled do
   it 'should check if the xx1':
   end

   it 'should check if the xx2':
   end
end
```

Comment: how do you do the check :unless => @app.name = "test"

Comment: describe " ... ", :unless => @app.name == "test" do ?